Finding a formula which involves iteration
Suppose I have the following set:
a = {0.338636, 0.422347, 0.449019, 0.477665, 0.533535, 0.541595, 0.573555, 0.578846, 0.601858, 0.609386};

And I need to find $r_i$ which is given by the formula:
\begin{equation}
r_i=\frac{\text{Min}(d_i,d_{i+1})}{\text{Max}(d_i,d_{i+1})}
\end{equation}
where $d_n=a_{n+1}-a_n$
How to evaluate it using Mathematica?
Edit
Here's the code I used:
a = {0.338636, 0.422347, 0.449019, 0.477665, 0.533535, 0.541595, 
   0.573555, 0.578846, 0.601858, 0.609386};

d = Differences[a];

r = Table[
   Min[d[[i]], d[[i + 1]]]/Max[d[[i]], d[[i + 1]]], {i, 1, 
    Length[d]}];


So you are able to write it in Latex then what prevents you from writing it in Mathematica code?

@azerbajdzan, I tried but got wrong answer.

@codebpr, even if you get a wrong answer, you should include the code you have tried in your question, so that others can give you some concrete advice and feedback.

Ok, I will add my non-working code in the question.

Use {i, 1, Length[d] - 1} and problem solved.

d = Differences[a];
r = (Min[#]/Max[#]) & /@ Partition[d, 2, 1]
(* {0.31862, 0.93109, 0.512726, 0.144263, 0.25219, 0.165551, 0.229924, 0.327134} *)


Using SequenceCases:
a = {0.338636, 0.422347, 0.449019, 0.477665, 0.533535, 0.541595, 
   0.573555, 0.578846, 0.601858, 0.609386};

SequenceCases[a, {a1_, a2_, a3_} :> Min[a2 - a1, a3 - a2]/
  Max[a2 - a1, a3 - a2], Overlaps -> True]


{0.31862, 0.93109, 0.512726, 0.144263, 0.25219, 0.165551, 0.229924, 
0.327134}


BlockMap[Apply[Divide]@*Comap[{Min, Max}], Differences[a], 2, 1]


Using MinMax
d = Differences[a];
Divide @@@ MovingMap[MinMax, d, 1]


{0.31862, 0.93109, 0.512726, 0.144263, 0.25219, 0.165551, 0.229924,  0.327134}

We could also Sort the length 2 windows:
Divide @@@ MovingMap[Sort, d, 1]

